# Save current date via button click into NSUserDefaults

Tags: xcode, swift, nsdate, nsuserdefaults

**I've been trying to save the current date on the iPhone via Button click to the NSUserDefaults but it won't work. I don't really know how to get the current date, save it as a var and call it in the function. but I've given it a try:**

```
  @IBAction func saveButtonTapped (sender:AnyObject){

    var date = NSDate()

    var userDefaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    var timeList:NSMutableArray? = userDefaults.objectForKey("timeList") as? NSMutableArray

    var dataSet:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    dataSet.setObject(date, forKey: "time")

    if ((timeList) != nil){
        var newMutableList:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray();

        for dict:AnyObject in timeList!{
            newMutableList.addObject(dict as NSDictionary)
        }

        userDefaults.removeObjectForKey("timeList")
        newMutableList.addObject(dataSet)
        userDefaults.setObject(newMutableList, forKey: "timeList")

    }else{
        userDefaults.removeObjectForKey("timeList")
        timeList = NSMutableArray()
        timeList!.addObject(dataSet)
        userDefaults.setObject(timeList, forKey: "timeList")
    }
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
 @IBAction func saveButtonTapped (sender:AnyObject){

    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if var timeList = userDefaults.objectForKey("timeList") as? [NSDate]
    {
        timeList.append(NSDate())
        userDefaults.setObject(timeList, forKey: "timeList")
    }
    else
    {
        userDefaults.setObject([NSDate()], forKey: "timeList")
    }
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}
```

To read back the list

```
if let timeList = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("timeList") as? [NSDate]
{
    println(timeList)
}
```